# Accessing the terminal from GNOME without a mouse

Tags: lenovo, trackpad

I have a new Lenovo G560e, and have just installed Ubuntu 10.04.  But the laptop's trackpad does not work!

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingHardwareDetection suggests some commands to run before reporting a hardware issue -- but my immediate problem is that I can't work out how to access the terminal from GNOME without a mouse!

Any help / suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: For the record, my problem seems to have been related to this -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/34501/comments/88 -- and the suggested solution, reloading the psmouse module worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to start the Terminal very quickly.

Comment: it works with 10.04?

Comment: Does this work with 10.04 ?

Comment: This works in 11.04 for sure, and I think it should work with 10.04 LTS, though it's been a while so I'm not completely sure on that. If it doesn't work, you may have to open your Keyboard Shortcuts, find the entry for starting a terminal, and manually entering it (or some other key combination you might prefer).

Comment: Works with 12.04 running within Parallels (Control + Option + T).

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut Alt-F2 allow to enter a command: write `gnome-terminal`. Alternatively Alt-F1 bring you to the main menu.

Also, to switch between application you can use Alt-TAB.

Comment: Who needs a mouse anyway?

Comment: yeah!, down with the GUI, CLI ftw!11!1

Comment: Thanks, this works on CentOS whereas the accepted answer doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the shortcuts how to access the terminal ;if you want you can control the mouse using the keypad.

Try to go to **System->Preferences->Keyboard**, under **Mouse keys** :

Check **Pointer can be controlled using the keypad**.

[image]

Comment: This looks potentially useful -- but any idea how I can do this without a mouse?

Comment: Use Alt + F2 to access the keyboard Preferences. Or use Alt+F1 to access the main menu then navigate to system.

Comment: Alt-F1, System->Preferences->Keyboard, then using arrows, tabs, and enter you can obtain all you want